BillingClient - queryProductDetailsAsync returns error statuses (2, 6, 12) many times
I'm using billing client in my game in order to let people purchase in app item.
According to my logs, many users aren't able to purchase the item, as purchase flow doesn't start.
Logs show that most of the users that launch the purchase flow, getting "stuck" at queryProductDetailsAsync method, which results in errors:
int SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
int ERROR = 6;
int NETWORK_ERROR = 12;
The thing is that I'm using queryProductDetailsAsync after a success calling to startConnection - I don't understand how come it can be a network/connection error.
According to my tests, It always succeeds.
I also did a test on my friends phone and it succeeds either.
Furthermore, I do see some success purchases of some users.
So I'm guessing it is not a configuration problem.
All of the failures are from logs coming from users devices
Here's the code my BillingHelper class:
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import com.android.billingclient.api.*
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

class BillingHelper
{
    // region Enum

    enum class PurchaseStatus
    {
        PURCHASED,
        PENDING
    }

    // endregion

    // region Companion

    companion object
    {
        private const val TAG = "BillingHelper"
    }

    // endregion

    // region Listener

    interface BillingHelperListener
    {
        fun purchaseStatusUpdated(itemId: String, status: PurchaseStatus)
    }

    // endregion

    // region Properties

    private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null
    private var context: WeakReference<Context>? = null
    private var listener: BillingHelperListener? = null
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    // endregion

    // region Init

    fun init(context: Context)
    {
        this.context = WeakReference(context)
    }

    fun setListener(listener: BillingHelperListener)
    {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    // endregion

    // region Purchase flow

    fun launchPurchase(activity: Activity, itemId: String, block: (purchaseStarted: Boolean) -> Unit)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "launchPurchase - $itemId")

        connectToBillingClient { connected ->

            KLog.i(TAG, "launchPurchase - $itemId. connected? - $connected")

            if (connected)
            {
                prepareSkuForPurchase(activity, itemId, block)
            } else
            {
                handler.post {

                    KLog.i(TAG, "launchPurchase - $itemId. invoking false")
                    block.invoke(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun connectToBillingClient(block: (connected: Boolean) -> Unit)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient")

        getBillingClient()?.let {

            if (it.isReady)
            {
                KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient - already connected")
                block.invoke(true)
                return@let
            }

            it.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener
            {
                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult)
                {
                    KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient::onBillingSetupFinished")

                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                    {
                        KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient::onBillingSetupFinished - connected")
                        block.invoke(true)
                        return
                    }

                    KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient::onBillingSetupFinished - invoking false")
                    block.invoke(false)
                }

                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected()
                {
                    KLog.i(TAG, "connectToBillingClient::onBillingServiceDisconnected - invoking false")
                    block.invoke(false)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private fun prepareSkuForPurchase(activity: Activity, itemID: String, block: (purchaseStarted: Boolean) -> Unit)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "prepareSkuForPurchase - $itemID")

        val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
        skuList.add(itemID)

        val productList =
            listOf(
                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(itemID)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build()
            )

        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setProductList(productList)

        getBillingClient()?.queryProductDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->

            KLog.i(TAG, "prepareSkuForPurchase::queryProductDetailsAsync - billing result - $billingResult")

            /**
             * PROBLEM IS HERE - ACCORDING TO THE LOG - IT SAYS:
             *   1 - billing result - Response Code: ERROR, Debug Message: An internal error occurred.
             *   2 - billing result - Response Code: NETWORK_ERROR, Debug Message: An internal error occurred.
             *   3 - billing result - Response Code: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, Debug Message: Timeout communicating with service.
             */

            var purchaseStarted = false

            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty())
            {
                launchSkuPurchase(activity, skuDetailsList[0])
                purchaseStarted = true
            }

            handler.post {

                KLog.i(TAG, "prepareSkuForPurchase::queryProductDetailsAsync - invoking purchase started? - $purchaseStarted")
                block.invoke(purchaseStarted)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun launchSkuPurchase(activity: Activity, productDetails: ProductDetails)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "launchSkuPurchase - $productDetails")
        val params = ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setProductDetails(productDetails)
        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setProductDetailsParamsList(listOf(params.build())).build()
        getBillingClient()?.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
    }

    private fun handleSuccessPurchase(purchase: Purchase)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "handleSuccessPurchase - $purchase")
        KLog.i(TAG, "handleSuccessPurchase. state = - ${purchase.purchaseState}")

        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
        {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged)
            {
                acknowledgePurchase(purchase)
            } else
            {
                handler.post {

                    listener?.purchaseStatusUpdated(purchase.products.firstOrNull() ?: "", PurchaseStatus.PURCHASED)
                }
            }
        } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING)
        {
            handler.post {

                listener?.purchaseStatusUpdated(purchase.products.firstOrNull() ?: "", PurchaseStatus.PENDING)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun acknowledgePurchase(purchase: Purchase)
    {
        KLog.i(TAG, "acknowledgePurchase - $purchase")

        val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken).build()

        getBillingClient()?.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams) { result ->

            KLog.i(TAG, ":acknowledgePurchase::status - ${result.responseCode}")

            if (result.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
            {
                handler.post {

                    listener?.purchaseStatusUpdated(purchase.products.firstOrNull() ?: "", PurchaseStatus.PURCHASED)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val purchaseUpdateListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->

        KLog.i(TAG, "purchaseUpdateListener::onPurchasesUpdated : $billingResult")

        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && !purchases.isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            val purchase = purchases.first()
            handleSuccessPurchase(purchase)
        }
    }

    // endregion

    // region Billing client

    private fun getBillingClient(): BillingClient?
    {
        val context = this.context?.get() ?: return let {

            KLog.i(TAG, "getBillingClient - context is null")
            null
        }

        var billingClient = this.billingClient

        if (billingClient == null)
        {
            KLog.i(TAG, "getBillingClient - creating new billing client")
            billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .setListener(purchaseUpdateListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()

            this.billingClient = billingClient
        } else
        {
            KLog.i(TAG, "getBillingClient - using existing billing client")
        }

        return billingClient
    }

    // endregion
}

As you can see - the problem is in queryProductDetailsAsync method.
What am I missing?
I'm using:
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:7.0.0'
